# Java:Is it possible to name a collection?

Tags: java

I was wanting to put my own unique identifier for my collection instances.
Hashcodes can uniquely identify a collection but that is not what I am looking for. Something like this..

```
List<Integer> classOneStudentIds = Arrays.asList(123,135);
classOneStudentIds.name = "classOne";
List<Integer> classTwoStudentIds = Arrays.asList(145,138);
classTwoStudentIds.name = "classTwo";
```

It does not appear to be possible...

Not very relevant when the code is non-recursive and the main program knows what the lists stand for. However, for recursive solutions, I can see it being helpful that the collection is able to identify itself based on what the programmer has named it.

For the following snippet for Tower of Hanoi solution, it would help to not have to use hashCode but rather a meaningful name relevant to the use case at hand..

```
   Integer elem = pegOne.removeFirst();
   System.out.println("Move element " + elem + " from " + 
    pegOne.hashCode());
   pegThree.add(elem);
   System.out.println(" to " + pegThree.hashCode());
```

Is there a way for a collection to identify itself?

Comment: You can create a Custom Collection wrapper class.  That can have a underlying List and some extra properties like you mentioned above.

Comment: Do accept one of the answers below that you find the best.

Comment: Yes - I had considered wrappers but that felt like an overhead every time I hit a use case like that.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible directly, but have a meaningful Object.

```
class ListWithId {

   String identifier;
   List<Integer> classStudentIds;
   // more properties you want to add

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class WrapperCollection<T> {

   public String name;
   public List<T> list;

}
```

The above wrapper collection code will help you achieve the same.

Changes I would do:
1.  Better naming.
2.  Better encapsulation - private fields and immutability.
3.  List operations.